# Inner Join Help - How to order table join?

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

**Class** (PK = Tutor)

Columns: `ID / Tutor / Room`

**Teacher** (PK FK = Tutor)

Columns: `Tutor / Contact`

I want to join both tables.
Does it matter what order the tables are joined?

ie.

```
SELECT Class.ID, Class.Tutor, Teacher.Contact
FROM **Class INNER JOIN Teacher** ON Class.Tutor=Teacher.Tutor
```

or could I do it the other way round and **Teacher INNER JOIN Class** instead?

Both tables also share a common column name **Tutor**.
Does it matter if I use Class.Tutor or Teacher.Tutor in the query?

Comment: The order of the joins does not matter when you are only using inner joins.  It does matter which tutor you use.  You have to know which one you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an `INNER JOIN`, the order does not matter; the result set you will get will contain all the rows from both `Class` and `Teacher` where the common field `Tutor` matches, whichever order you specify `Teacher` and `Class`.

When you use an `OUTER JOIN`, the order does matter; I would recommend looking at the answers to [What is the difference between Left, Right, Outer and Inner Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins).

Comment: Also, as `Class.Tutor` equals `Teacher.Tutor` in the join condition itself, and *only because it is an INNER JOIN*, it doesn't matter which one you output in the `select` list. If it were an OUTER JOIN, one may be NULL whilst the other has a value.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the order matters. 
Selecting from class and joining Teacher will show only those classes that have a teacher
Selecting from teacher and joining Class will show only those teachers that have a class

Depending on what you are trying to achieve you'll know which is most relevant.

I'd recommend using "left join" though, it will give you all the classes even if they don't have teacher assigned etc

FWIW "class" is likely to be a reserved word in your database, server side script and client side scripting languages. I'd find another word for that table name.

Comment: As it's an `INNER JOIN`, the order doesn't matter; the set of results will be the same in both cases (although the order in which those results are *returned* may differ).